# Setting form and inputs to "ng-dirty" programatically

Tags: javascript, angular

I've never worked with Angular or Angular2 before, but now I have to make an update to a site running on my domain that is using Angular2. I need to programatically fill out a textbox and click submit, but after setting the textbox's value using .value = "val", it still treats the textbox as if it is empty.

I've read up on angular and now understand the concept of ng-dirty and ng-pristine, but programatically changing the class to ng-dirty still doesn't work.

It seems like even if I change the classes, it is still not updating the "pristine" status and it still considers the textbox empty.

I've read about "markAsDirty()" and tried using it but I get "markAsDirty is not a function". I just need to figure out how to update the page so that it realizes that the textbox is not empty and lets me submit the form.

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
Page form:

```
<form id="form_register" novalidate="">
    <div class="form-steps">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" data-is-regex="true" data-mask="[a-zA-Z0-1\.]+" id="username" name="username" ngcontrol="username" placeholder="Username" required="" style="color: black !important;" tabindex="13" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="password" name="password" ngcontrol="password" placeholder="Password" required="" style="color: black !important;" tabindex="14" type="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" tabindex="4" type="submit">
                                   Log In
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

My problem is that this:

```
document.getElementById("username").value = "testuser";
document.getElementById("password").value = "testpass";
document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info")[0].click();
```

ends up giving me a message saying the username and password are required even though there is a value showing in the textbox. Simply clicking on the textbox, typing a character, then deleting it will allow me to submit the form, but I need to accomplish this without user interaction.

Comment: Please show the relevant "[MCVE]" code to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Also, please use the `angularjs` tag if you are using AngularJS 1.x OR the `angular2` tag if you are using Angular 2, not both, unless you are actually mixing the two frameworks.

Comment: Alright I have updated my post to reflect what both of you have said.

Comment: Are you using template driven or reactive forms? Importing FormsModule or ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: @silentsod I'm not sure. Someone else wrote this site, I'm just trying to make this small change. I've tried looking through the files, but haven't seen anything that indicated FormsModule vs ReactiveFormsModule. Is there an easy way to tell? Thanks btw.

Comment: Well, they would most likely be in the root module of your application. If it's a really old version it could be REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES or FORM_DIRECTIVES.

Answer (score 1):

You are filling the forms with native javascript and that is not updating the angular model.  In your backing component you need to use ngmodel to connect your elements to the component.  Then update the variables in the component and everything will reflect correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I do notice I have access to an "ng" object. Would the values be somewhere buried in that?

Comment: Take a look at [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html).  In the section titled "Two-way data binding with ngModel".  Best bet it to bind each form input to a string in your component.  The bind the submit button on your form to a function in your component like this (click)="mySubmitFunction()".  Write all your validation in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there are a few issues with your code that I can see and I'll walk through getting this to work as expected.

For a Template driven form, create and assign the form group variable (which will make our shiny `NgForm` which we later attach controls to with `ngControl`) in the template, and lets bind the submit function while we're at it:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(myForm.value)" id="form_register" novalidate="">
```

Each of our inputs is standalone and not yet tied to the form, to do so we'll want to clear the `ng-` classes which should be managed by Angular 2 and add our [(ngModel)] binding to a property.

```
<input autocomplete="off" class="form-control" data-is-regex="true" data-mask="[a-zA-Z0-1\.]+"
                      id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" ngControl="username" [(ngModel)]="username"
                      required style="color: black !important;" tabindex="13" type="text">
```

We're going to disable our submit if the form is invalid:

```
<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info" tabindex="4" type="submit">Log In</button>
```

Our class has the `username` and `password` properties that we bind to, and our submit function:

```
export class App {
  password: string;
  username: string;

  submit(value) {
     console.log("submitting: " + JSON.stringify(value));
  }
}
```

Finally, if we really want to mark things dirty programmatically this way we will have to grab our template variable in our code with a `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild('myForm') formGroup;
password: string;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.formGroup.control.markAsDirty();
}
```

To do it per control we either need to access it through our `formGroup` variable or add individual template variables on the inputs we can grab with `[(ngModel)]="username" #username="ngModel"`, for instance.

here's a plunker you can play with to try and develop your understanding: http://plnkr.co/edit/ukJ1kq2UFBvtoCsxbyba?p=preview